# Google Analytics CDN Cookie Issue on a Non-www domain

Tags: google-analytics, cdn

I am trying to apply the Cloudfront CDN on one of my Wordpress websites, using W3 Total Cache.

Someone I know told me to change my Google Analytics to ['_setDomainName', 'www.example.com'] in order to explicitly track the main site and not the CDN sub domains

But my site is a non-www site and has been indexed in google according to that.

Will this change prevent tracking? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

First: This change will not prevent tracking.

Second: Why would you want to prevent tracking from user accessing your site through the CDN?

This is exactly the contrary to what you should do. To the final user it shouldn't matter if he is seeing a cached version or not. Also in terms on analytics for you it's probably better to have a view of the big picture.